# React native - console logging with remote debugging

Tags: react-native

Tried to do a bit of research without finding a result, however:

I am connecting to my development server over the same wifi network and using hot reloading to update react native Application on physical device, however I can’t seem to find a way to display the console output like I normally would through the temrinal. Normally I would build my app with physical cable and display log through the console and use react-native log-android.

What’s the way to show console logging when connecting wirelessly?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the option Debug Js remotely, which opens a new tab in the browser and from there if you press f12 and go to developer tools ,in the console tab there you can view all the console log statements. And to start Debug Js remotely, you shake the phone and the option will be displayed. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yups. Glad you made it. Can you make my answer as the accepted answer then. Will be greatful